# How to maintain a certain number of rows using triggers in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

For example I have a table which is used for logging. So very old data is useless and there are no reasons to leave it in the table. I want create a trigger which will delete old rows if number of existing rows more than 10 for example. What I already have:

```
CREATE TABLE log (
    logId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    firstLogin DATETIME NOT NULL,
    lastLogin DATETIME NOT NULL,
    fingerprint VARCHAR(64) CHARACTER SET BINARY,
    ip VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL,
    accountId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (accountId)
        REFERENCES accounts (accountId)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (logId)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

DELIMITER |

CREATE TRIGGER logbeforeinsert BEFORE INSERT ON log
    FOR EACH ROW 
        BEGIN
            SET @rowcount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM log WHERE accountId = NEW.accountId);
            IF @rowcount > 9 THEN
                DELETE FROM log WHERE accountId = NEW.accountId LIMIT 1;
            END IF;
        END;
|

DELIMITER ;
```

But with this trigger inserting stopped at all after number of rows had reached 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trigger tries to write to the same table (`DELETE` is write access), that it is inserting into - this is not supported.

As you have a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger, failure of the trigger means failure of the `INSERT`.

You need either to trigger the delete from an operation, that does not write to `log`, or rethink your model.

Comment: This is bad. Seems one way is to implement delete operation in application logic.

Comment: A typical way: 1. Put the cleanup logic in a stored proc, 2. get `LAST_INSERT_ID()` after INSERT, 3. $If lastInsertID mod N ==0 call cleanup stored proc, with N being a reasonable number (e.g. 1000)