# Setting a limited numer of rows on a MySQL Table, and deleting the old ones to free space

Tags: mysql, sql, automation

Is it possible with MySQL to set on a given table a limited(maximum) number of rows so that when this value is reached, MySQL will remove old rows to allow insertion of new ones automatically ?

Comment: no. but you can use transactions and simple tricks, like `delete from yourtable where id <= max(id)-20`, assuming your ids won't have "holes" in the sequence.

Comment: You could do it with a trigger.

Comment: Apparently that doesn't work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296423/how-to-maintain-a-certain-number-of-rows-using-triggers-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can write cron jobs or mysql events to delete the rows on regular interval.

Comment: when you talk about cron jobs i suppose it's with php scripts, if so, i already knew that, but need a way to perform that with MySQL only if possible. unless MySQL also has cron jobs ?

Comment: I was talking about cron jobs which can be set on server. This link describes how to set cron jobs on linux [Create Cron Jobs on linux](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/)